# Fixing overlapping of show().fadeout() animation. Also by using .stop() the animation does not reset itself

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Also by using `stop()` the JQuery animation with `show().fadeout()` does not make the "reset" and overlaps the previous making a one-flow animation.

I'm going completely mad over this.

Here the code that breaks my mind

```
<script>
$(document).on('mouseenter','#a', function(e){
    console.log('in');
    msg('In');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','#a', function(e){
    console.log('out');
    msg('Out');
});

function msg(str, delayMs=1500, speed='slow'){
    $("#msg").html(str);
    $("#msg").stop().show().delay(delayMs).fadeOut(speed);
}
</script>
<center>
<div id="a">EVENT</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</center>
```

with a little fiddle added [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0a2horbm/)

How to fix it?

How to get a result that stops the previous animation 'instantly' like if there was `.hide()` and makes working the `.show().delay(delayMs).fadeOut(speed)` correctly?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do from your question, but there is [an example in the docs](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) about using `.stop()` for animations on `mouseneter` and `mouseleave` which seems relevant: "*We can create a nice fade effect without the common problem of multiple queued animations by adding `.stop(true, true)` to the chain*". Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Don't Panic - *It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do from your question, but there is an example in the docs about using .stop() for animations on mouseneter and mouseleave which seems relevant: "We can create a nice fade effect without the common problem of multiple queued animations by adding .stop(true, true) to the chain". Is this what you are trying to do?* **I'm in panic, but yes :)**

Answer (score 0):

OOOOK. After writing with @Don't Panic in comments you can use `.stop(true, true)` https://api.jquery.com/stop/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('mouseenter','#a', function(e){
    console.log('in');
    msg('In');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','#a', function(e){
    console.log('out');
    msg('Out');
});

function msg(str, delayMs=1500, speed='slow'){
    $("#msg").html(str);
    $("#msg").stop(true,true).show().delay(delayMs).fadeOut(speed);
}
</script>
<center>
<div id="a">EVENT</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</center>
```

Tnx all <3

---

### Edit.

**mumbling...**

But, if you use the `click` event it does not work good the same

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','#a', function(e){
    console.log('CLICKED');
    msg('CLICKED');
});
function msg(str, delayMs=1500, speed='slow'){
    $("#msg").html(str);
    $("#msg").stop(true,true).show().delay(delayMs).fadeOut(speed);
}
</script>
<center>
<div id="a" style="cursor: pointer;">EVENT</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</center>
```

Comment: I see the same behavior whether you're triggering on `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` or `click`.

Comment: @kmoser *I see the same behavior whether you're triggering on mouseenter/mouseleave or click.* Not true. There's the overlap. Try adding `delayMs` to see it better